# Force iPad to stay awake while app is running a process

Tags: ios, ipad

When my app starts for the first time, if the iPad goes into sleep mode the app doesnt run properly. Is there a way to force the iPad to stay awake during this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can disable the sleep mode programmatically, your correct approach here is to fix the bug.

You cannot prevent the user from switching the device off manually anyway.

Comment: there is a large file being downloaded from a database and if it sleeps this gets corrupted on ipad, so if we can force awake mode it would fix the problem. Do you think there is a better way to do this?

Comment: You can only disable the automatic sleep with  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES]; and enable it again when done. It doesn't solve the problem entirely, though. You should check the download progress and status, and maybe file integrity. Resuming a cancelled download is much nicer than restarting all the time, especially on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't expected user to do something (wait) to make you app run properly. From you reply on @Eiko you have to downloaded something on the server, in this case could you delayed the download until its really need and prompt user for some text before your download, with this approach user will get some idea of what is he waiting. This is all I can think of with your information.

Comment: The user is aware they are waiting and were not trying to prevent them from turning their ipad off. The whole purpose of the app is to allow the user to access this large database and for them to interact with it. Once app has downloaded the information for the very first time(after install) there is no issue. When they are loading after install if the ipad happens to go into sleep mode it interrupts file exchange and the user must start it up again.

Comment: In that case you could try http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use it has resume download feature (I never try it yet) and the application delegate 
– applicationWillResignActive:
– applicationWillEnterForeground:would help you with this resuming I think.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using something like the ASI library to make downloading the file easier.  http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Is the problem that you are in the middle of a database transaction and the download is a key piece of the transaction?  If so you should defer saving the database commands until you are ready to commit OR even better, download the file before making DB changes.